# Is there any way to use $filter and $sum in the same $project?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a document in my aggregate pipeline that looks like this:

```
{
  scores: [
    {type: 'quiz', score: 75},
    {type: 'quiz', score: 62},
    {type: 'final', score: 34},
  ]
}
```

I'm using `$project` to transform it, and I'd like to get the sum of the the quiz scores, is there a way I could somehow chain my `$filter` and `$sum`.

I know that I could potentially use two `$project`s, but the way I currently have my pipeline set up would force me to continue reproject a ton of keys in my second project, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES!

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { 
        "totalQuiz": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$score", 
                    "as": "s",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$s.type", "quiz" ] }
                }
             }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I think $filter will return an array and $sum will not consider an array summation

Comment: @Parshuram OP is using MongoDB 3.2 check the [release note](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#accumulator-expression-availability).

Comment: Ohh but what version the author uses?

Comment: The author is using 3.2. I know that because [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is new in 3.2

Comment: This gives 0 as in case of nested properties

Answer (score 9):

You would need help from another operator that maps the scores embedded documents into an array of values that you can **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-project-stage)**. You can do that using the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** operator as in the following:

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "scores": 1,
            "quiz_total": { 
                "$sum": {
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": "$scores", 
                        "as": "item", 
                        "in": { 
                            "$cond": [ 
                                { "$eq": [ "$$item.type", "quiz" ] }, 
                                "$$item.score", 
                                0 
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }    
        }   
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582ac9619602e37d2794acd3"),
    "scores" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 75
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 62
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "final",
            "score" : 34
        }
    ],
    "quiz_total" : 137
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although Styvane's answer is a more direct solution to the document I asked about, your solution works even if there are other numerical values in scores array, which was the case for me.